# Power BI angular1 authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to integrate Power BI into angular 1 application. From my research i came to know i have to follow following process

1. Authenticate User and get access token
2. By using this token get Embed token

But i am struck at first step. How to authenticate?

i have made an API call to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token

with parameters :

grant_type:'password',
client_id: clientId,
resource:'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api',
scope:'openid',
username:username,
password:password,
client_secret : client_secret

i am getting following response :

```
"error": "invalid_client",
"error_description": "AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided.\r\nTrace ID: 51694a76-ebf8-4923-9a8c-2a1ad2e35600\r\nCorrelation ID: f25bedeb-7aa9-45db-a93f-d8dfd85d0f19\r\nTimestamp: 2017-11-27 06:02:56Z",
"error_codes": [
    70002,
    50012
],
"timestamp": "2017-11-27 06:02:56Z",
"trace_id": "51694a76-ebf8-4923-9a8c-2a1ad2e35600",
"correlation_id": "f25bedeb-7aa9-45db-a93f-d8dfd85d0f19"
```

i don't know i am calling right API or not. whats the use of resource in parameter?

can anyone please help! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get auth token by making a post request to `https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token` with following `params`

`grant_type,Client_id,resource,username,password`

Also from the error its look like you are sending an invalid `client secrate`

[image: Check out full request]

Comment: what is resource in params?

Comment: you can try with the same `https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.PowerBI`

Comment: Thanks for reply. i have created new client_secret in azure portal under keys and tried, now i am getting invalid Resource error